# Concatenate 2 or more pyspark dataframes with different columns, but same number of rows (add dataframes horizontally)

Tags: python, pyspark

Context:

I'd like to concatenate 2 or more pyspark dataframes that have different columns, but same number of rows (similar to pd.concat would do by setting the axis)

Let's say we have these dataframes:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 2]], ['a', 'b'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([[3, 333], [4, 444]], ['c', 'd'])
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([[555, 5], [666, 6]], ['e', 'f'])
```

How can we concatenate them so that we get a dataframe like this:

```
df_final = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 2],[3, 333], [4, 444],[555, 5], [666, 6]], ['a', 'b','c', 'd','e', 'f'])
```

I was trying this:

```
    df_final = df1.join(
        df2).join(df3)
```

but I get over 100+ rows (seems like it's repeating the data)

Thanks!